# Footsteps sfx sampler ?

Tags: footsteps, sfx, sampler, random

Simple question i hope.
I was wondering if there was some free vst sampler around to play footsteps sound (or other multiple sounds) randomly.

You play a note on the keyboard and you get a random sequence of the multiple sounds you've loaded at a chosen rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Kontakt, it's pretty easy to create a footsteps instrument, then load this script into your script editor: http://peteroregan.com/scripts.html

Set the dropdown that says "Sequential" to "Full Random" and adjust the NotesAbove and NotesBelow...  It'll do what you want, but quality may vary.  The script is made for varying repeated notes in single-sample instruments, not for fully random sound effects.

Just go with WWise.

Comment: Kontakt seems to be the right sampler ! But i can't manage to get the script to appear...that's weird. There's no "script" folder in program files. I'm using kontakt 4.

Comment: I only have 3.5, so I'm not sure if they changed anything, but I remember that the scripts folder was way harder to find than it should have been.  I'll find the path to mine, when I get home, and hopefully that'll help you.

Answer (score 3):

You could also set up a sampler to use velocity switching so louder footsteps are triggered when you press harder (or grittier, or more heel-to-toe, or whatever you want the main variable to be, if any, or just random). Given MIDI's resolution, you could therefore dial in up to 127 different footsteps based on note-down velocity with a single key, and be able to change them by just changing the velocity setting of each note (a snap with most MIDI-aware DAWs).

Comment: Great idea, NJ.

Answer (score 2):

Sound Dude, what DAW are you using?

Jon Margulies is writing 365 days of Ableton Live tips. And he recently talked about setting up such a random sample selector in Live. http://www.heatercore.net/2010/07/lets-get-random-.html

Comment: I'm using Cockos' Reaper.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't find a sampler to your liking, you can go with a video game development tool like [WWise](http://www.audiokinetic.com/en/products/wwise/introduction).  These tools are free to download and use, fit those kinds of needs well, and are very fast and flexible. The companies make money when you license them for implementation into a game.

Answer (score 1):

'KFootsteps' = [Free Kontakt footsteps instrument.](http://alejandrocabrera.net/software.php) Click on 'Libraries' and then on download.
'Edward' = [59$ Kontakt    Footsteps-instrument.](http://tovusound.com/shop/edward-foleyart-instrument/)
And Google 'AudioSteps Pro' from 'Audiogaming' (Sorry I only get to share 2 links because I'm new on this site)

Comment: Hi Wasaia, links are not considered a proper answer (that's why it's limited to 2). Can you elaborate on your use of these libraries, because it looks like a sales pitch now.

Comment: I just found these useful instruments a few weeks ago because I'm searching for some good footstep-instruments for cartoon-foley. I only have tried the free KFootsteps. The other ones are now above my budget so haven't tested them yet. Though the 59 dollar-instrument 'Edward' might be adopted by me in the near future. It just seemed useful links for the question asked.
Guess I don't get the system here on this site quite yet. So if I understand correctly one may only post something one has already used him/herself?

Comment: Yes, experience is more important than 'encyclopaedic knowledge' of 'all the plugins in the world' :)

Comment: Okay, true. But I know from my own experience these footstep-instruments are difficult to find when you're browsing the web. Actually I found them by chance. So I like to help people save time.

Comment: i understand and where are grateful for enthousiastic contributors. please keep posting and if you do, take the time to explain your ideas/experiences, we like that and the persons asking will do to!